# Monitor latency by IP on a bridge-enabled host

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring, latency

Is there a tool which captures packets, measure latency in realtime and display it with some IP filtering options for Windows ?

*My particular setup :*

Internet -> Router -> Host Master -> Host Slave

**Host Master** (Win7) have two ethernet cards : eth0, eth1.

eth0 and eth1 are **bridged**. Host Master give Host Slave internet.

With this setup, I can capture packets from and to **Host Slave** on **Host Master** (WireShark, for eg)

*The Scenario :*

**Host Slave** will send and receive packets to and from external IP adresses. I can't predict this IPs.

I need to live monitor **Host Slave** packets exchanging latency on **Host Master**.

*What I've tried :*

I tried to play with the Wireshark IO graph, but it seems that there is no options which can do that.

Thanks in advance,